# How to determine reciprocity between groups in a network?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a directed network with male and female nodes. I would like to determine if the proportion of reciprocated ties from males to females is higher/lower than the proportion of reciprocated ties from females to males. Currently I do this in a relatively manual way.

I create an edge attribute using `which_mutual(graph, es = E(graph))`.

Then I remove all mutual dyads, using 
`subgraph.edges(graph, which(E(graph)$mut==TRUE)`.

This leaves only asymmetric ties in the graph.

Then I compute the count of ties from Female to Male and from Male to Female and divide that by the total number of edges in the graph.

But there has to be a function that allows to determine reciprocity between groups. Am I missing it?

Thanks
Bogdan

Comment: What package are you using for the graph?

Comment: igraph, but could also switch to sna/network if there is a better option in those.